# how can I find class name of content provider which answered my intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I sent implicit intent (with startActivityForResult), I received answer (with onActivityResult), in this answer I received uri of data the content provider sent me - but I'm interested who was the one who answered me and sent me this data. Can I somehow programatically find the class name of content provider which answered my implicit intent?

Comment: if you come back from another activity then in setResult(int) you can pass diffrent int values from diffrent activities and when you will come back on the MainActivity,then inside onActivityResult(),use switch case to identify which activity returned to you.

Comment: But it's not mine this activity which answers my intent.

Comment: Sorry please elaborate, you mean your Activity called from another which have not created or something else

Comment: My activity called some other activity which I did not create.

Comment: You mean you called buit-in applications using intents like Contacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of a way to to get the provider from an implicit intent, but you can always resolve the intent yourself using [resolveActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#resolveActivity%28android.content.pm.PackageManager%29).  It is what is used under the hood to resolve implicit intents.  To get the class the intent resolves to, you'd do something like

```java
   ComponentName cName = intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager());
   Log.d("resolve","class = " + cName.getClassName());
```

In theory, if you then do a `startActivity...(intent)` the same component should be selected.  If you want to be sure, you can always update your intent with

```java
 intent.setComponent(cName);
```

Essentially, this is resolving the implicit intent to an explicit one to know what component you are sending to before you launch the intent.

Comment: That's what I wanted. Thanks!